# how to handle nested exception in java?

Tags: jdbc

I am trying to connect to mysql database. I am using try catch while establishing connection. 
I want that I should be able to know what exception was caught, so that, I can show appropriate error message. 
e.g if I pass incorrect hostname, i should show Wrong hostname provided. 
One way to do is get class name of runtime exception class. but nested exception is being thrown like this..

> There was some error while establishing connection to the
>   databasecom.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link
>   failure due to underlying exception: 
>   -- BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION -- java.net.UnknownHostException  MESSAGE:
>   localhsost  STACKTRACE:  java.net.UnknownHostException: localhsost  at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:867)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1246) 
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1197)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1128)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1064)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:246)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:271)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:222)  at
>   accessMySQL.accessMySQL.createConnection(accessMySQL.java:24)  at
>   test.main(test.java:16) 
>   -- END NESTED EXCEPTION -- Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms
>   ago.  Problem in establishing connection.

Now I would like to know that class name UnknownHostException, so I can setup a condition like

```
if(e.getClass().toString() == "UnknownHostException")  
System.out.println("Exception caught while connection to database. Hostname appears to be incorrect");
```

please help !!
P.s that typo in hostname is deliberately there to generate exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (e.getCause() instanceof UnknownHostException) {
    // ...
}
```